# Android studio DateFormat error - refuses to select android.text.format.DateFormat

Tags: android, android-studio

I think this may be an Android studio bug and unfortunately it has stopped me in my tracks.

I am using (and selecting!) android.text.format.DateFormat as my DateFormat class, but I am getting an error: "Required: android.text.format.Dateformat, Found: java.text.DatefFormat") and it will not compile.

I am not importing or using java.text.DateFormat but Android Studio is insisting I am.

Here is the code:

```
package org.example.kev.criminalintent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;

public class CrimeFragment extends Fragment {

    private Crime mCrime;
    private EditText mTitleField;
    private Button mDateButton;
    private CheckBox mSolvedCheckbox;
    private DateFormat dateFormat;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mCrime = new Crime();

        dateFormat = DateFormat.getLongDateFormat(this.getActivity());

    }
```

Comment: The error is on the last line of code: "dateFormat = ..." It is underlined and gives the above error. I have tried fully typing the class "android.text.format.DateFormat" instead of "DateFormat" and get exactly that same error.

Comment: Interestingly, if I change the dateFormat and timeFormat variables to type "java.text.DateFormat" it all works, but I do not know why. I hope someone can enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason, `android.text.format.DateFormat.getLongDateFormat` returns a `java.text.DateFormat`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#getLongDateFormat%28android.content.Context%29

Comment: Yup. That is the crux of it and I have to say I am confused to why - but that fixed it. Thanks.